# Trigger child only, not the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden input file inside of a label, which I made as a browse button. On other place I have another button which can trigger the input file to browse files.

Here is the HTML:
This is the input file

```
<label class="btn-u btn-u-green">
    <span class="fancy-label">Choose file</span>
    <input class="form-control hidden uploaded-file" name="upload" type="file">
</label>
<button type="button" class="btn-u btn-u-blue btn-u-upload hidden">
    Upload 
    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
</button>
<input name="act" class="act" type="hidden" value="add">
```

This is the trigger button

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-edit" type="button"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
```

And this is the script, where I try to click on '.uploaded-file' without clicking the '.btn-u' label. This to change hidden field value to edit or add.

```
$('.btn-edit').click(function(){
    $('.act').val('edit');
    $('.uploaded-file').click();
    return false;
});

$('label.btn-u').click(function(){
    $('.act').val('add');
});
```

However, it keeps making the value for '.act' = 'add', because everytime I trigger the '.uploaded-file' click, it clicks also 'label.btn-u', so that the value of '.act' is always 'add'. So how can I only trigger the input file without clicking the wrapper?

==========================================================================

It seems it works now if I do

```
$('.uploaded-file', e).click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation();}).click();
```

Comment: Can't understand what you exactly want to do.

Comment: OP wants to change the `.act` value depending on what was clicked.

Comment: yes.. click on `.btn-edit` will change the value of `.act`. The problem is, the value will be changed back to default value.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.uploaded-file').click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation();});
```

// edit final declaration

```
  $('.btn-edit').click(function(){
        $('.act').val('edit');
        $('.uploaded-file').click();
        return false;
 });

 $('.uploaded-file').click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation() ;});
```

Comment: This will not trigger '.uploaded-file' to click

Comment: I made this like `$('.uploaded-file', e).click().click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation();});`. It works, but only after second click.

Comment: It seems that it works when I do this `$('.uploaded-file', e).click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation();}).click();`. Thanks!

Comment: You have put it in the wring place i think. Check edit

Answer (score 0):

Stop parent trigger with `stopPropagation` :

```
$('.uploaded-file').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: This will stop the propagation of the click event on `.btn-edit`, but not the one that occurs on `.uploaded-file`.

Comment: Thanks , answer Edited

Comment: I made this like `$('.uploaded-file', e).click().click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation();});`. It works, but only after second click.

Comment: It seems that it works when I do this `$('.uploaded-file', e).click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation();}).click();`. Thanks!